# Build git log statement using bash script, throws ambiguous argument '%an' error

Tags: git, bash

I want to construct and execute the following git log statement to get summary of commits for yesterday for specific authors: `name1` and `name2`, so the final desired executed git log should be as follows:

```
git log --author name1 --author name2 
        --since yesterday --reverse
        --pretty=format:"%h - %an , %ad : %s" > commits.txt
```

As you may notice output is redirected to `commits.txt` file.

The output `commits.txt` file should finally contain some text like this:

```
350411e - name1, Mon Apr 18 18:03:01 2016 +0200 : Fix bug X
366411e - name2, Mon Apr 18 18:05:06 2016 +0200 : Introduce feature Y
752411e - name1, Mon Apr 18 18:11:12 2016 +0200 : Merge version Z
```

Here's my code in `script.sh`

```
team=( name1 name2 )

function create_commits_log_file () {
    authors=''
    for author in "${@}"
    do
        authors="$authors --author $author "
    done
    git_log_statement="git log $authors --since yesterday --reverse --pretty=format:\"%h - %an , %ad : %s\" > commits.txt"
    echo "$git_log_statement"
    $git_log_statement
}

create_commits_log_file "${team[@]}"
```

Unfortunately when I run it as `bash script.sh`, it throws an error:

> git log  --author name1  --author name2  --since yesterday --reverse
>   --pretty=format:"%h - %an , %ad : %s" > commits.txt
>
> fatal: ambiguous argument '%an': unknown revision or path not in the
>   working tree.
>
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git 
>   [...] -- [...]'

Despite that if I run the `echo`'ed git command on console it works perfectly!

What is the problem ? and how may I fix it ?

---

UPDATE - Attempt:

Based on comments, I also tried to execute the git log command directly without storing it in a variable as follows :

```
team=( ashraf.bashir diego.palacios )

function create_commits_log_file () {
    authors=''
    for author in "${@}"
    do
        authors="$authors --author $author "
    done
    git log $authors --since yesterday --reverse --pretty=format:\"%h - %an , %ad : %s\" >commits.txt
}

create_commits_log_file "${team[@]}"
```

But I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those cases in which we hit what is described in [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050): you store a command in a variable and when you try to execute it, fails.

Instead of saying

```
var=command   # store command
$var          # execute it
```

Just execute it:

```
command
```

In your case, instead of

```
git_log_statement="git log $authors --since yesterday --reverse --pretty=format:\"%h - %an , %ad : %s\" > commits.txt"
$git_log_statement
```

Just say.

```
git log $authors --since yesterday --reverse --pretty=format:"%h - %an , %ad : %s" > commits.txt
```

I tested it locally and it worked well.

Comment: Same error: fatal: ambiguous argument '%an': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]', I updated the question with this attempt

Comment: @AshrafBashir my fault. I missed unescaping those `"`. See my updated attempt using `--pretty=format:"%h - %an , %ad : %s"` instead.